# R: How to make objects and its values into a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, object

First time asking question here.
I am a rookie in R, and I run into this problem.

example: I have the following objects stored.

```
A_1 <- 3
A_2 <- 6
A_3 <- 8
B_1 <- 0.9
B_2 <- 1.1
B_3 <- 1.2
```

....(I have 90 objects)

Wanted return as a data frame:

```
name value
 A_1   3
 A_2   6
 A_3   8
 B_1   0.9
 B_2   1.1
 B_3   1.2
```

I know that I could use `as.data.frame(ls())` to get object names into a data frame. But don't know how to get the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mget` on `ls` to return a named `list` of key/value pairs and `stack` it to a two column `data.frame` (assuming these are the only objects created in the global environment)

```
out <- stack(mget(ls()))[2:1]
```

If we are naming objects with a uppercase letter followed by underscore and some digits

```
pat <- "^[A-Z]_\\d+$"
out <- stack(mget(ls(pattern = pat)))[2:1]
```

Comment: Yes, I can use `pattern()` inside `ls()`! Why are you so smart, master!